# Importing lib's css inside the component styles is throwing dependency not found while it's installed

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component, tippyjs

```
<style lang="scss">
@import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';

//@import "@/assets/vars.scss";

.chart-tooltip-slim {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.chart-tooltip {
  min-width: 260px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 30px;
```

I have the following code inside the vuejs 2 app. The thing is that the lib is installed and it's working when I import only the js part. However when I import the styles it throws a loader error about dependency not found. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@import '~tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
```

should work.

---

You can also use

```js
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
```

...in JavaScript (typically you'd place all vendor style imports in `main.js`).